# "Ich bin der Meinung, dass die Kleidung dieser Saison entsetzlich ist." - sind or ist?

Tags: grammatical-number, grammar-identification

When talking about clothes in German (die Kleidung) I thought that the noun refers to an uncountable number of clothes, as in English.

So upon reading the sentence

> Ich bin der Meinung, dass die Kleidung dieser Saison entsetzlich ist.

I was slightly confused. If we are talking about clothes in the plural sense, wouldn't the verb in the subordinate clause be "sein" i.e.

> Ich bin der Meinung, dass die Kleidung dieser Saison entsetzlich sind.

Comment: If a noun is in singular, the verb is also in singular. Doesn't matter if it's plural sense or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Die Kleidung* ([[1]](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kleidung), [[2]](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kleidung)) stands for a *single set* that contains *many items*, and from a grammatical point of view, it's singular (the plural would be "Kleidungen", but that's rarely used). It behaves somewhat similarly to *fashion* or *clothing*:

- *"clothing **is** terrible"* (not *"clothing are terrible"*)
- *"fashion **is** terrible"* (not *"fashion are terrible"*)

so, *"die Kleidung ist entsetzlich"* is correct.

Even if it were plural, *"sein"* would still be wrong. It would have to be replaced by *"sind"*:

- *Ich bin der Meinung, dass die Jacken dieser Saison entsetzlich sind.*

Answer (score 2):

[Kleidung](https://dwds.de/wb/Kleidung) is a proper noun used grammatically in **singular** but in a logical plural meaning in that we usually mean several pieces of clothing (*Kleidungsstücke*) by that. Still, it is not a [singulare tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum#Singulare_tantum) because, though rarely used, a plural **Kleidungen** does exist.

> Denn langlebige Kleidung **ist** in der Herstellung tendenziell teurer. <sup>Die Zeit 43, 2017</sup>

This is not to be confused with **Kleider** which in the plural form to [Kleid](https://dwds.de/wb/Kleid) is used synonymously to *Kleidung*.

> Kleider **machen** Leute.<sup>[Gottfried Keller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Keller)</sup>